# Django-import-export before_import_row to automatically create object if it does not exist

Tags: python, django, excel, django-import-export

I'm facing the current issue when using Django-import-export:

inside my admin.py :

```
class QuestionResource(resources.ModelResource):
category = fields.Field(
        column_name='category',
        attribute='category',
        widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Category, 'category')
    )

class Meta:
    model = Question
    fields = ['id', 'question', 'category', 'answer',]
    # exclude = ('created', 'modified', 'verified', 'count', 'user_created')

# PREVIOUS THINGS I TRIED: 

# def _post_import(model, **kwargs):
#   query = self.fields['category']
#   category = Question.objects.get_or_create(category=query)
#   return category

# def before_import(self, dataset, dry_run, *args, **kwargs):
#   query = self.fields['category']
#   for q in query:
#       Category.objects.get_or_create(category=q)

# def before_import_row(row, *args, **kwargs):
#   category = self.fields['category']
#   Category.objects.get_or_create(category=category)

def before_import_row(row, *args, **kwargs):
    category = row.fields['category']
    Category.objects.get_or_create(category=category)
```

As you can see I added the previous things I tried as comments. The error I receive is:

```
Errors

Line number: 5 - Category matching query does not exist.
Pokemon, 9526, Is er een voorvak?, Ja, bij de Alpha is een voorvak.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/iam-tony/.envs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 457, in import_row
self.import_obj(instance, row, dry_run)
File "/Users/iam-tony/.envs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 329, in import_obj
self.import_field(field, obj, data)
File "/Users/iam-tony/.envs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 316, in import_field
field.save(obj, data, is_m2m)
File "/Users/iam-tony/.envs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/import_export/fields.py", line 115, in save
cleaned = self.clean(data)
File "/Users/iam-tony/.envs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/import_export/fields.py", line 69, in clean
value = self.widget.clean(value, row=data)
File "/Users/iam-tony/.envs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/import_export/widgets.py", line 334, in clean
return self.get_queryset(value, row, *args, **kwargs).get(**{self.field: val})
File "/Users/iam-tony/.envs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 403, in get
self.model._meta.object_name
questions.models.DoesNotExist: Category matching query does not exist.
```

What am I missing? I can't seem to find any documentation on this (or there is but I don't understand it)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

What is Category#category field? The name of the Category? A string?

try resetting that field to be a primary key of the created Category:

```
def before_import_row(self, row, **kwargs):
    name = row.get('category')
    (cat, _created) = Category.objects.get_or_create(name=name)
    row['category'] = cat.id
```