# django-import-export: Line number: 1 - get() returned more than one Block -- it returned 2

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin, django-import-export

I am importing data to a `model/table` with foreign key.

It upload some rows but exclude others by throwing the error as:

```
Line number: 1 - get() returned more than one Block -- it returned 2!
, HARYANA, 11, FATEHABAD, 195, FATEHABAD, 641, AHLISADAR, 57891
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/webtesting/django_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 660, in import_row
self.before_import_row(row, **kwargs)
File "/home/webtesting/Excel/DAMU_Excel_Upload_AMFU_DAMU/damuwhatsapp/resources.py", line 89, in before_import_row
(cat, _created) = Block.objects.get_or_create(block_name=block_name)
File "/home/webtesting/django_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/webtesting/django_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 657, in get_or_create
return self.get(**kwargs), False
File "/home/webtesting/django_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 499, in get
raise self.model.MultipleObjectsReturned(
damuwhatsapp.models.Block.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Block -- it returned 2!
```

the successful imports were as:
[image: successful]

But it throws errors for other rows having a similar data structure

[image: Error]

The data in CSV is as:

[image: CSV]

The models.py file is as:

```
####################################################################################
class Village(models.Model):
    state_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(100)])
    district_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    district_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(1000)])
    block_name = models.ForeignKey(Block, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    block_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(8000)])
    village_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    village_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True, validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(750000)])

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Village_Names'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.village_name
```

The resource.py file is as:

where I have excluded the `id` column, as it is blank
and block_name is the foreign key from some other model

```
class VillageResource(resources.ModelResource):
    state_name = fields.Field(column_name="state_name", attribute="state_name")
    state_id = fields.Field(column_name="state_id", attribute="state_id")

    district_name = fields.Field(column_name="district_name", attribute="district_name")
    district_id = fields.Field(column_name="district_id", attribute="district_id")

    block_name = fields.Field(column_name='block_name',
                              attribute='block_name',
                              widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Block, 'block_name'))
               
    block_id = fields.Field(column_name="block_id", attribute="block_id")

    village_name = fields.Field(column_name="village_name", attribute="village_name")
                              
    village_id = fields.Field(column_name="village_id", attribute="village_id")


    class Meta:
        model = Village
        exclude = ['id']
        skip_unchanged = True
        report_skipped = True
        import_id_fields = ('state_name', 'state_id','district_name','district_id','block_name','block_id', 'village_name','village_id')
    
    def before_import_row(self, row, **kwargs):
        block_name = row.get('block_name')
        (cat, _created) = Block.objects.get_or_create(block_name=block_name)
        row['block_name'] = cat.block_name
```

The admin.py file is as:

```
class VillageAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    resource_class = VillageResource
    list_display = ['id', 'state_name', 'state_id','district_name','district_id','block_name','block_id', 'village_name','village_id']
    search_fields = ["village_name"]
    filter_horizontal = ()
    list_filter = ()
    fieldset = ()
admin.site.register(Village, VillageAdmin)
```

The table of model Village is as:

[image]

Why is it that the model accept some rows values and throws errors in others
and how to rectify it?

Comment: Hi Please refer to the (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22063748/django-get-returned-more-than-one-topic) link. I have resolved this.

Comment: It has 18 answers but no one is related to Import-export module of Django @PinkleshParjapati

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve here, mate.

As per your stack trace, you have the following code:

```
(cat, _created) = Block.objects.get_or_create(block_name=block_name)
```

`get_or_create` retrieves one (1) model instance, or creates a new one if none matching the provided criteria (block_name=block_name) is found. But you have multiple rows (on your database) with the same `block_name`. Hence, Django throws the `MultipleObjectsReturned` exception because, as said before, this method is used to retrieve one single instance.

Comment: I took ```def before_import_row(self, row, **kwargs):
        block_name = row.get('block_name')
        (cat, _created) = Block.objects.get_or_create(block_name=block_name)
        row['block_name'] = cat.block_name``` from here @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49800332/django-import-export-before-import-row-to-automatically-create-object-if-it-does

Comment: Even before adding this code block, the same error was there.

Comment: I am just trying to upload the table, but it accept some rows while rejects others, Not sure why.

Comment: So before the ```def before_import_row``` code block, there were 9 unique columns in total as: ```'id', 'state_name', 'state_id','district_name','district_id','block_name','block_id', 'village_name','village_id'``` out of which I was excluding ```id column``` @Kauê Oliveira

Comment: Search your database for columns with the same `block_name` and delete the duplicates for this code to work (maybe). If deleting said columns is not an option, this code will not work for you.

Comment: Also, avoid copying/pasting code from the internet. Try to build your solution from start and read the documentation/ask for help when stuck.

Comment: But the data or table does not have multiple column with name ```block_name```, it is a single column only.

Comment: it's not multiple columns, it's multiple rows.  The error is occurring because you have multiple rows in `Block` with the same `block_name`.